# If $f$ is a density function of $\xi$, is there any way to express $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)^2 dx$ in terms of the expected value of $\xi$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

Let $\xi$ be a random variable in $\mathbb{R}$ with probability density function $f$.

**The question:** Is there any way to express
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)^2 dx$$
 in terms of the expected value of $\xi$? or or is there an upper bound of this expression  in terms of the expected value of $\xi$?

**Remark:** I thank in advance any collaboration from a suggestion to a reference to a book that can help me.

Comment: Consider $f(x) = 2/\sqrt{x}$ for $x\in (0,1)$ and zero else. The integral doesn't even exist.

Comment: The normalization factor should be $(1/2)$ instead of $2$.

Comment: The mentioned integral is $E[f(\xi)]$. If $f$ is concave, then we should have $E[f(\xi)] \leq f(E[\xi])$ by Jensen's inequality.

Comment: @BGM I think there is no concave density function. If f is concave and $y=ax+b$ is a tangent line to the graph than $ax+b \geq f(x) \geq 0$ for all x which is false. However examples where $f^{2}$ is integrable are easy to find: any bounded density function has this property.

Comment: Yes it only possible for a density to be locally concave within a finite support only, and that should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_a(x) = \frac{1}{2} a I_{[-\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{a}]}(x)$ for $a > 0$. Then $f_a$ is a probability density for all $a > 0$ and the expected value of the corresponding distribution is always $0$. But

$\int _{\mathbb{R}} f_a(x)^2 dx  = \frac{1}{2}a$

which ranges from $(0, \infty)$ for $a > 0$. Thus there is no upper bound in general.

Nevertheless, if $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ and compactly supported in $[0, \infty)$ with $f' \geq - C$ for some $C > 0$, then

$\int _{\mathbb{R}} f^2(x)dx = - \int _{0} ^{\infty} x \cdot 2f(x)f'(x) dx \leq 2C \mathbb{E}[\xi]$

by integration by parts.